# Ex-pats in the Philippines and the 'Real Property Tax'

Tags: taxes, uk-citizens, philippines

I've recently heard about the 'Real Property Tax' in the Philippines. It appears to be a tax based on value of owned 'real property' that goes to the local government. Unfortunately I can't really find out much more about it.

It's not clear what counts as 'real property' -- in my particular case I'd like to know if a condo unit counts and who (if anyone) is liable for the tax but any general, clear, and preferably official information would be useful.

Is it safe to assume that if I'm due to pay tax that someone will inform me somehow? I.e. if I haven't got any demand for money I don't need to pay any -- that would seem to make sense but it wouldn't surprise me if that's not the way it works. I know, in most places, ignorance of the tax law is no excuse.

I'm trying to get answers from other avenues, and I'll post if I have any success, but I don't really want to pay someone to look at this -- the information must be freely available somewhere, no?

Answer (score 3):

It's a tax levied on each property by the local government (municipio). As a condominium owner, you have to pay RPT on your unit, plus a share of the RPT for the building. The latter is usually included in your association dues. You won't receive any demand for payment. You'll find that in the Philippines, you're just "supposed to know". It's payable quarterly, although most people pay it annually to get a discount. If it's not paid there is penalty interest and in extreme cases, the municipio can apply to the court to place a lien on your property. You'll find it difficult to sell your unit with unpaid RPT.